# HTML Data Not Available On RDP/Terminal Services Clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, clipboard

I'm parsing HTML data that is currently available on the clipboard (Clipboard.GetDataObject).  However, I was surprised to find that when copying data from a webpage in an RDP session, the HTML format is not available and is instead replaced with "OEMText".

Can anyone discribe why this occurs or a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

I think RDP just filters that out.  It does pass RTF though, and some OLE formats.
However, "OEMText" is not a replacement, it's always available whenever plain text is present.  You typically have Text, OEMText, and UnicodeText.